# Suggestions for a tensioned rope effect?

Tags: sound-effects, recording, recommendations, foley, sound-libraries

Hello! First time poster but (relatively) long time reader here. I am working on a kung fu short film and am currently stumped concerning a particular sound effect.  Any suggestions would be so, so great.  Here is the setup:

There is a man bound with natural fiber rope and partially elevated off the ground over a knife.  The rope is fed through a pulley and then secured to the ground.  I know in my mind's eye...er...ear in this case, exactly what I'm looking for as far as an exaggerated rope tension "sound," but am having a tough time finding or describing it. Can anyone think of anything connotative?  I have spent time on SoundSnap and running through things I could record, but haven't found the ticket yet.

Also, a big shout out to Tim Prebble for his amazing sound effect collections at Hiss and a Roar.  This project would be a lot tougher had I not bought the Swishes and Vegetable Violence collections.

Cheers!

Matt Tibbs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wicker! Take a wicker basket and wrench it in opposing directions with each hand. It totally sounds like heavy natural fibers under tension - because it is - but the dryness makes it louder and more dramatic than actual rope. Worked for me, but a cheap experiment to try out regardless!

Comment: @NoiseJockey, I totally wouldn't have thought of wicker, but that's why I posted! I will give that a whirl. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A foley artist I met a few years back used an old Leather Wallet which they twisted and rubbed their thumbs over.  This created a stretching/creaking/squeaky sound.  You could use any other tense and strong material, I created a similar sound pushing my thumbs into some tense paper.

This would create a starting point and you should get enough material to cut together/pitchshift and play around with.

Comment: @Audious Sound I will definitely try that and report back...I'm also grabbing some leather shoes to twist. Thanks!

Comment: + 1 on the leather too... used and approved. a thin leather jacket that you twist and pull on.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z382bFcMgcc&feature=player_embedded#!

I just had to post this vid. Its more like a wood creak, but with rope involved:)
That little box is just great thought out!
Check out the other Roger Gregg vids. He is really inventive.

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 3):

You can make some good rope sounds by getting a big handful of long thick succulent grass and twisting it with your hands.  Its fairly quiet though so better to do it in a quiet studio with good recording gear.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Matt!

If you have access to a microphone and recorder, I recommend you doing some performances on your own rather than continue to scour online libraries. Some useful props would be:

- Rope

  - Hemp
  - Nylon
  - Fiber
- Leather
- Rubber

  - try a bungee cord

That should get you headed in the right direction. Have fun - and post the results for all to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I needed a simillar sound and I used a leather, pleathure, or just plastic (can remember) bag, wet my hands slightly and rubbed it. Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I found that after all the great suggestions here, wicker indeed made the most appropriate sound for beefing up that rope scene, closely followed by old leather.

Answer (score 0):

I find that you need to layer it depending on the action of the screen. Leather with wicker has worked for me in the past- a leather belt twisted together to get the tension and then the wicker for the organic compounds of the rope. Has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck wrapping a piece of rope around a dried piece of wood with the bark still on.