# Tree Grown Sound Effect (Tree Ents in LoTR)

Tags: sound-effects, ableton-live

Hey there, First time here :D

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on achieving the tree 'grown' sound used on the Tree Ents from Lord Of The Rings and World Of Warcraft.

The sound is like a arcing of wood, almost a deep floor board 'grown', it is fairly hard to describe. But i was wondering if there is a cheat (even synthetic) ways of getting this sound without having to get hold of a load of wood etc etc.

I'm a "expert" Ableton Live so I'll understand many synthetic solutions!

Thanks - Caius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually suggested this in [another thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/suggestions-for-a-tensioned-rope-effect), but for a tense rope sound effect.  But trying stretching leather with your hands or thumbs as a base for the sound. Then maybe add some splintering wood.  Pitch shift around until you find the right pitch, and work from there.

I think somebody else in the same thread mentioned a Wicker basket (credit to that person).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think Audious Sound is talking about a thread made by NoiseJockey :
http://www.noisejockey.net/blog/2009/09/08/thrift-store-sounds-wicker-basket/
Sounds really nice

Answer (score 3):

why not try cutting open a pomegranate and squeezing one half slowly. It's a really nice thick woody sound. Put it through some effects and there you go. Plus you get to enjoy a little snack as you go! Be sure to do it face down over a bowl as it can get messy as some of the seeds pop.

Good luck