# How Did They Do That?? Vol. 4: Lord of the Rings Tree People

Tags: iconic-sounds

Following on from the previous how did they do that posts, I'm intrigued to find out if anyone knows how the moves for the tree people in Lord of the Rings was achieved. Heres a linky linky:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFzAxAEMwrY

Answer (score 2):

There's a great doc on the extended edition of LOTR:T2T that goes into some particulars about the sound design and talks specifically about the voice and footsteps of the Ent. Check it out "LOTR2: TT Sound Design part 1" around the 5 minute mark [here](http://designingsound.org/2009/12/the-sound-design-of-the-lord-of-the-rings-the-fellowship-of-the-ring-and-the-two-towers/).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas in this thread:
[Tree Grown Sound Effect (Tree Ents in LoTR)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/6126/tree-grown-sound-effect-tree-ents-in-lotr)

Contact mic + ice cracking might be another idea.